# How to run kernel 5.19 with Ubuntu 22.04 and ZFS?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, zfs

I have two AMD 6800XT graphics cards that have poor support with kernel 5.15

I'd like to upgrade to kernel 5.19. However, I also run ZFS. The current version in 22.04 is 2.1.5 which does not support 5.19.

https://www.phoronix.com/news/OpenZFS-2.1.5-Released

JonathonF maintained a PPA for ZFS backports. Sadly, he passed away.

Does anyone know if there are plans to update the ZFS packages in 22.04 to support ZFS 2.1.6+?

Comment: Why don't you install it yourself from [here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/releases)? It seems to be maintained. You'll need to compile it though...

Comment: You might find this repository useful: https://github.com/zabbly/zfs